# Getting postmeta value

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently creating a wordpress plugin that retrieves the value of the custom fields after insertion into the database.

I use p2theme and I add a text box (for the value of the custom fields) on the form in frontend.

post is added and the value of custom fields as well in postmeta.

But the problem is that in my plugins there's no value.

```
function recupere($post_id) {


  echo 'POST = ' . $post_id . ' / ';

  if (wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {
    return;
  }


  $post = get_post($post_id);

  $meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id, 'destinataire', true);

  echo 'meta = ' . $meta_values . ' <br />';
}
add_action('save_post', 'recupere');
```

Comment: `if(wp_is_post_revision()) return;` this code may be stop your function. try delete and run again.

Comment: Function is not stopped. programs show "meta = " There is no value.

Comment: I've also try to test with get_post_custom. and programs gives me an Array with _encloseme value